# Getting no projection from Dynamics CRM dataset

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to get data from Dynamics in my Data Factory, but somehow I'm not seeing column output when I try to use the dataset in my Data Flow.

When I use the 'Preview data' option in my Dynamics dataset I'm getting result, so that looks fine. But when I try to use my Dataset as a source in my Data Flow no columns/fields are visible in the  'Projection' tab.

[Source settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUYAd.png)

[Projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq2qq.png)

Has anyone ever had this problem? I've already spent hours on this, but I can't getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using a 'copy data' activity like this:

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jETH.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

First go to Dataset and In Schema tab click on Import schema.

[image]

Now go to Projection and click on Import projection.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source#projection

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

The problem with a CRM entity is that it has no Schema Import option. I already found another way to get the data I want by using a lookup. That works!